# Kubuntu 20.04 powers itself on every 1st of month at GMT without apparent reason

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, power-management

I have a strange thing with a Kubuntu 20.04 machine.
This machine is one of a couple that started as cloned images (and diverted a bit from this) so the setup and everything are essentially the same across 4 machines.
But only one behaves in a strange way.

This machine is powered off manually every evening at 5 pm and powered on manually at 7 am.
The power Switch is set to Power off, not sleeping, hibernating, or something.
But strangely, every first day of a month it powers itself on at exactly 0:00 GMT (which is currently 1 am in my timezone).

I haven't found an apparent reason for this, and frankly, I'm at a loss for where to begin to search.

Hardware is Metal, no VM, some Intel NUC
The Software is Kubuntu 20.04, the current version and all updates applied

```
$ uname -a
Linux  5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Any hints would be appreciated...

I checked for crontab entries, and possibly systemd issues without finding anything.
I found no ehthernet-wake-up packages or similar things floating through the network.

Comment: OS can't power on by itself. Probably there is some BIOS setting.

Comment: there is nothing apparent in BIOS either, Secondary Power settings are missing from this particular BIOS somehow

Comment: You might have enabled some settings to power on by itself.